# Merging Postgresql dump with production database

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql database that lost some records. I want to take a pg_dump SQL dump of the database from a few days ago and merge it with the current production database. A lot of the records are going to be duplicates so it can skip the duplicates. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`patch` could be you friend could try creating a new dump, we'll call it current_dump and do a `diff` against old_dump then use

```
   diff old_dump new_dump > patch.input
    (copy the new_dump) to another file at this point new.db.dump)
    patch new.db.dump patch.input
```

You might have to sort the sort the dump files before you do the diff and depending on how big your database is this might not really be practical.

Also be very careful and do this against a backup until you are sure its right.

Otherwise, maybe there are ETL type tools that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what kind of dump you are working with (plain, tar, or custom)...

If you have dblink available then you could restore to a different database and pull the data over to the production box.

A more convoluted solution might be to

1. restore the dump to a different database,
2. change the schema/table names to not conflict with anything in the production database,
3. dump the renamed tables and use that dump to get the renamed tables into the production database.
4. After all that you can then use plain SQL to find/insert the missing data.